# How To Evaluate Predictive Neural Network in Encog

Tags: java, neural-network, encog

We're a creating a neural network for **predicting typhoon occurrence** using several typhoon parameters as input. So far, we have been able to generate data and train the neural network using **Encog 3.2**. Right now, we need to evaluate the results of the training.

We're using the **ForestCover** project (in Encog 3.2 examples) as reference, however the said project's *Evaluation* code is for a classification neural network. Thus, we can't evaluate our neural network following said project's code.

We also checked the **PredictMarket** project (in Encog 3.2 examples) since it is a predictive neural network. But we're having a difficulty in using the MLData.

```
MLData output = network.compute(inputData);
```

We want to extract the contents of *output* and compare it to the contents of the **evaluation.csv** for neural-network evaluation.

**Is there a way we can extract/convert the *output* variable into a normalized value which we can then compare to the normalized evaluation.csv?**

or

**Is there a way we can modify the *ForestCover Evaluate.java* file to be able to evaluate a predictive neural network?**

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify how you normalized your data?

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy We normalized our data using the built-in data generation  in the ForestCover example in Encog 3.2 via OutputFieldRangeMapped. It automatically divides the data (75%-25%) into the training.csv and evaluation.csv files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C# example (Java should be similar) which writes out a .csv file (TestResultsFile) with both the de-normalized expected and actual results so you can compare them with an Excel graph.

```
var evaluationSet = (BasicMLDataSet)EncogUtility.LoadCSV2Memory(Config.EvaluationNormalizedFile.ToString(),
    network.InputCount, network.OutputCount, true, CSVFormat.English,
        false);

var analyst = new EncogAnalyst();
analyst.Load(Config.NormalizationAnalystFile);

// Change this to whatever your output field index is
int outputFieldIndex = 29;

using (var resultsFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Config.TestResultsFile.ToString()))
{
    foreach (var item in evaluationSet)
    {
        var normalizedActualOuput = (BasicMLData)network.Compute(item.Input);
        var actualOutput = analyst.Script.Normalize.NormalizedFields[outputFieldIndex].DeNormalize(normalizedActualOuput.Data[0]);

        var idealOutput = analyst.Script.Normalize.NormalizedFields[outputFieldIndex].DeNormalize(item.Ideal[0]);


        var resultLine = String.Format("{0},{1}", idealOutput, actualOutput);
        resultsFile.WriteLine(resultLine);

    }
}
```

Much of this came from ideas from [Abishek Kumar's Pluralsight Course](http://pluralsight.com)

If you really want to compare Normalized values, just remove the two calls to "Denormalize".

Comment: Thank you very much for this insight! We will try following this code, and we will update you of the results.